# kill ruby daemon process within a rake task

Tags: ruby

I am using needing to start and stop a server during some rake tasks. I am using the following code:

```
task :start_server do
  job = fork do
    system `http-server ./_site -p 4000`
  end
  Process.detach(job)
  @pid = Process.pid
end

task :stop_server do
  puts "stopping server"
  system Process.kill('QUIT', @pid)
end
```

The start works fine but I cannot get it to stop.

I am calling these tasks within capistrano deploy e.g. `after 'pdf:generate_pdf', 'pdf:stop_server'`

I dont get an error but I can still see pages being served by the web server.

Is there a better way to end the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this command stops the http-server perfectly.

```
task :stop_server do
 system("pkill -f http-server")
end
```